# Connection close method doesnt work, too many clients error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, c3p0

Why connection close doesnt work in this code? I tried way without finally block by creating connection in try() but after executing testDbConnection a few times I have too many connections error and when I am trying to connect to my database by pgAdmin I see too many clients connected. How can I resolve it? Why closing connection doesn't work?

```
 private List<DataSource> getDataSources() {
        connectionsNumber = 2;
        List<DataSource> dataSources = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= connectionsNumber; i++) {
            Connection connection;
            DataSource dataSource;
            String jdbcUrl = environment.getProperty(String.format("database%d.url", i));
            String user = environment.getProperty(String.format("database%d.username", i));
            String password = environment.getProperty(String.format("database%d.password", i));
            ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            try {
                cpds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cpds.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
            cpds.setUser(user);
            cpds.setPassword(password);
            cpds.setMinPoolSize(3);
            cpds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
            cpds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
            cpds.setMaxIdleTime(1);
            cpds.setMaxConnectionAge(600);
            cpds.setMaxStatements(500);
            dataSource = cpds;
            dataSources.add(dataSource);
        }
        return dataSources;
    }
```

```
public void testDbConnection() throws SQLException {
        String query = "select id from users;";
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        List<DataSource> dataSources = getDataSources();
        for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
            try {
                connection = dataSource.getConnection();
                st = connection.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Connection");
                }
            } finally {
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.close();
                }
                st = null;
                rs = null;
                connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Too many clients' comes from the server, not the client, and it comes during open, not close, it comes during open. You appear to be merely testing the platform here. Solution: don't.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to achieve here? You are using a connection pool, so you shouldn't be surprised that physical connections remain open (that is the entire point). Either you need to reduce your pool sizing, or you need to raise the maximum number of connections. Your code seems to be artificial, so you want to explain your real problem instead. Also, please read up on try-with-resources, your fragile `finally` blocked can be removed if you use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion,when using the c3p0, `connection.close()` is not really closing the connection, just put it back in the pool.if you want to  clean up the DataSource,you can use `DataSources.destroy(dataSource);`

Comment: Doing that makes no real sense though. Keeping the connection open is the entire point of a connection pool like c3p0. It sounds more like the OP has an XY problem.

Comment: I think he has opened too many `dataSource` in his tests.As you said,doing that makes no real sense.Just a solution.